# How to solve the error message : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I copy a section of code from the the official website of '[Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#hex-tiles)':

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import linear_cmap
from bokeh.util.hex import hexbin

n = 50000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = np.random.standard_normal(n)

bins = hexbin(x, y, 0.1)

p = figure(tools="wheel_zoom,reset", match_aspect=True, background_fill_color='#440154')
p.grid.visible = False

p.hex_tile(q="q", r="r", size=0.1, line_color=None, source=bins,
           fill_color=linear_cmap('counts', 'Viridis256', 0, max(bins.counts)))

output_file("hex_tile.html")

show(p)
```

When i ran this program , i got a error message about this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAPCZ.png)

```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "d:\vscode-text-files\hex_tile.py", line 12, in 'module'
> bins = hexbin(x, y, 0.1)
> File "D:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\hex.py",
> line 198, in hexbin
> df = pd.DataFrame(dict(r=r, q=q))
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you incidentally assigned `None` to the variable `pd`, didn't you?

Comment: do you have pandas installed ? also check out the doc https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/util/hex.html bokeh is doing an import of pandas and assigning to a variable pd...since the error was at that line..i think it wasn't able to find pandas..please look into it

Comment: I forgot to install Pandas! Thanks to all !

Comment: As a maintainer of the project, it is helpful if SO questions have actual answers associated. Can someone add an answer here (rather than just a comment)